# Issue in Koa.js for jaeger tracing with Istio

Tags: node.js, koa, jaeger, opentracing, distributed-tracing

I am facing issue in jaeger tracing with Koa.js microservices.I haven't change anything regarding jaeger at my code level .I only install istio at AKS cluster and internally its taking tracing from there.But its showing tracing between two microservices only.I require full tracing like if I am getting response from four microservices then four microservices will show in tracing together but in my case only two microsrvices are only showing.

Do I need to make change in my all repos regarding jaeger headers ?
Currently all my microservices are written in Nodejs Koa.js framework.

Thanks.